# Get only remote branches that have already been merged into master/develop

Tags: git, github, ls-remote

```
git ls-remote --h <domain_specific_url>.git 'refs/heads/*'
```

which lists all the branches created on remote repository.

But I would like to extend this command to use `--merged` option, since I would like to get lists of branches which are already merged to develop/master

something like:

```
git ls-remote --h <domain_specific_url>.git 'refs/heads/*' --merged develop/master
```

Is this possible?

I could find many solutions, but I don't want to work with cloned repository. I need simply one command which takes repository URL and works.

Comment: So 'git branch -r --merged master' wouldn't be an option for you?

Comment: probably no, it will also work for cloned repository...

Answer (score 12):

the good new is that *gitbash* also provides some usefull Un*x utilities:

```
 git branch -r --merged master | grep "origin/"
```

Comment: But here in this case how should I specify "url of remote repository"? The above command works only when you have local repository. Isn't it?

Comment: please suggest me if functionality for git branch can be enhanced by specifying only url without having local repo... or any other git command

Answer (score 4):

This *cannot* be done without making a clone.  It's as simple as that: the hash IDs you get from `git ls-remote` uniquely identify commits, but unless you have the commits that *come before* those commits, the only way to tell if some `refs/heads/branchname` is an ancestor of `refs/heads/master` is if they have the exact same hash ID.  That only suffices for a branch that was *just* merged.

Note that some servers provide their own (non-Git) interfaces, and at least one of those (GitHub) shows you that some branch is "merged" (and can therefore be deleted).  This is *not* something you can access using `git ls-remote`.

Comment: Could you please help me with some hints about such interfaces? I am beginner to git

Comment: The only one I've used is GitHub. GitHub shows a purple "merged" icon on the web page if the branch in question is merged to master. But you'd be much better served by just making a clone: that's how Git is intended to be used.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. Ultimately I wanted to automate my script where I can clean branches. As of now I can work on clone and see if I can get better option in future :)

Comment: Ok Sorry.. 
I tried following command:

git branch --remote --merged develop/master |grep 'feature/*' |grep -v '>' |grep -v master |grep -v develop |xargs -L1 |cut -d"/" -f2-|xargs git push origin --delete

But I can see branches which has not been merged to develop are also getting deleted. For example some feature branches which was merged to develop and some feature open which are open... All are getting deleted.

Can someone help me with more details?

Comment: I mean I have scenario where I dont have any PR created on that branch. Its a empty branch.

Comment: @Neha: this is a new question, about hwo to use `git branch --remote --merged` to find merged branches and send delete requests to the server. You can ask it as a new question, but I'd recommend doing a StackOverflow search first, as there are already questions of this form.

Comment: Regarding "not possible", doesn't `git merge-base --is-ancestor` play here? I think it's been around over 7 years, so maybe I misunderstand merge-base or this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53852911

Comment: @shannon: `git merge-base --is-ancestor` works great ... *on a clone*. The question was: "can this be done without making a clone", and the answer to that is still "no".